# Google Cloud Notebooks giving Error 524 while making inference

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-ai-platform, google-notebook

Getting a popup error while making inference in the notebook.
[image]
Code which gave the error

```
preds=[]
spans=list(test['span_text'])
for i in range(700,len(spans)):
    #print(i)
    try:
        preds.append(get_prediction(str(spans[i] )))
    except:
        preds.append([])
```

Popup Error

```
File Save Error for FineTuningBERT_Transformers.ipynb
<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang=en> <meta charset=utf-8> <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width"> <title>Error 524 ()!!1</title> <style> *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/logos/errorpage/error_logo-150x54.png) no-repeat;margin-left:-5px}@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/logos/errorpage/error_logo-150x54-2x.png) no-repeat 0% 0%/100% 100%;-moz-border-image:url(//www.google.com/images/logos/errorpage/error_logo-150x54-2x.png) 0}}@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/logos/errorpage/error_logo-150x54-2x.png) no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:100% 100%}}#logo{display:inline-block;height:54px;width:150px} </style> <a href=//www.google.com/><span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a> <p><b>524.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins> <p> <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>
```

Comment: Have you tried to follow up the recommendations in the troubleshooting [guide](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/notebooks/docs/troubleshooting#opening_a_notebook_results_in_a_524_a_timeout_occurred_error)?

Comment: @Nick_Kh Have not tried guide  but when I am not returning  tensor in the method get_prediction() resolved the issue. Not sure why?

Comment: Can you share more information about the Google cloud machine learning service you're using as well as the python package with `get_prediction()` method?